# A Set That is Closed but For Which $S + S$ is Not

Tags: real-analysis

$$\mathbb{Z}_+ \cup \{ -1 + \frac{1}{2}, -2+\frac{1}{3}, -3+\frac{1}{4}, -5+\frac{1}{6}, \cdots \}$$
Is apparently an example because $0$ is not in $S + S$.  I am unclear as to why it is not though.

$Edit$: I am the user that originally posted this question (I should have made an account) but I realized I am not sure why S itself is closed either.  Isn't zero a boundary point of S not contained in S?

Comment: What is S + S? Union? The union of two closed sets is always closed.

Comment: I think $S+S$ means the set consisting of sums of $2$ elements of $S$.

Comment: @Silencer It is the Minkowski sum. $A+B:=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: I rewrite your question with LaTeX. Please check whether I don't change the meaning or not. To write LaTeX by yourself, please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for example.

Comment: @Taro your revision was correct - it looks much better now.

Comment: Hi, your account @user71284 is not registered, which is why you seemed to have lost control to the question. Please create a new account, **register it**, and then visit [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to reclaim ownership of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of $S+S$ are either sums of two positive integers, hence positive, or sums of two negative numbers, hence negative, or sums $-n+\frac1{n+1}+k$ with $n\geqslant1$ and $k\geqslant1$. These last numbers are sums of an integer and $\frac1{n+1}$, hence not zero. Finally, no element of $S+S$ is $0$.

But $-n+\frac1{n+1}+n=\frac1{n+1}$ is in $S+S$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and $\frac1{n+1}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, hence indeed $0$ is in $\mathrm{cl}(S+S)$.

Comment: Excellent, so it seems very important that these sets are closed but NOT bounded.

Comment: @user71284, yes, because in a topological group the sum of a closed and a compact subset is closed. (See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80974/closed-sum-of-sets)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks.