# If $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact in $\mathbb R^n$ then $A+B=\{a+b : a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, sumset

> If $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact in $\mathbb R^n$ then $A+B=\{a+b : a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\}$ is closed. (In other words, the vector/Minkowski sum of a closed set and a compact set is closed.)

What I've tried so far: 
Let $ c_n $ be a sequence in $A+B$; $c_n =a_n+b_n$ where $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$. Since $B$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $(b_{n_k})$ which converges $b$ which is in $B$.

Now I'm stuck in how to show that the subsequence  $(a_{n_k})$ converges to some number in $A$ so that $(c_{n_k})$ converges to the sum of two limits in $A+B$.

Comment: You have to assume that $(c_n)$ is convergent to $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$, from there, all subsequences of $(c_n)$ is convergent to $c$.

Comment: You assume $c_k \to c$. Then $b_k$ converges on some subsequence, so let's just assume that $b_k \to b$, then $a_k \to c-b$.

Comment: why do we assume that? it may not be convergent at all?

Comment: @Esat, you are trying to show that $A+B$ is compact if you don't assume that the sequence is already convergent. You just need to show that an arbitrary *convergent* sequence converges to a point of your set.

Comment: This question offers a generalization of this statement: [Sum of closed and compact set in a TVS](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515496)

Answer (score 6):

As commenters indicated, a typical proof proceeds as follows:

1. Assume that $(c_n)$ is  a *convergent* sequence in $A+B$.
2. Write $c_n=a_n+b_n$.
3. Pick a convergent subsequence $b_{n_k}\to b\in B$.
4. Note that $a_{n_k}=c_{n_k}-b_{n_k}$ is also convergent. Let $a$ be its limit.
5. Conclude that $\lim c_n=\lim {c_{n_k}} = a+b \in A+B$.