# Show that Minkowski sum of a closed set and a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $E$ is closed and $K$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $K+E$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $E+K=\{x+y\,\,\, x\in E \,\,\, , y \in K \}$ is Minkowski sum.

I tried to show it by saying that $K$ is closed and bounded but I do not know how proof goes?

Comment: General case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515496/92038)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, $a\in\overline{E+K}$ then $\exists\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in E+K$ [Existence of such sequence is assured as $\mathbb{R}^n$ is First countable w.r.t usual norm] such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then $a_n=x_n+y_n$ for some $x_n\in E$ and $y_n\in K$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in E$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in K$. Since $K$ is compact so closed and bounded and $E$ is closed so $x_n\rightarrow x\in E$ and $y_n\rightarrow y\in K$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

So $x+y\in E+K$. Finally $||a_n-(x+y)||=||(x_n+y_n)-(x+y)||\le||x_n-x||+||y_n-y||\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Hence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x+y\in E$ so $\overline{E+K}\subset E+K$. reverse inequality is obvious. This completes the proof.

Comment: Could you tell me why we do not use boundedness? because if we say that $K$ is closed we have all the result.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya if both are only closed and one of them is not compact, the sum might not be closed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed]

Comment: @Sri Krishna Sahoo Thanks for the comment. Saeed I removed my last comment because it might not true and the beautiful example is given in SK sahoo's comment. Again thanks for the comment.

Comment: "taking a subsequence" step missing, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524603/92038).