# proof that the sum of two bounded, closed sets is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty, bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Define the set:$$C = A+B =  \{ \ a \  + \ b\ | \ a \in A \ \wedge \ b \in B \  \}$$
Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are closed. Prove that $C$ is also closed.

To prove that $C$ is closed, I will prove that $C^{c}$ is open. Hence, I have to prove that every point of $C^c$ is an interior point. Let $x \in C^c$. Now let $a \in A$. Because $x \in C^c$, $x-a \notin B$. Thus, $x-a \in B^c$. Because $B$ is closed, $B^c$ will be open. Thus, $x-a$ is an interior point of $B^c$. This means that there exists an $r>0$ such that $]x-a-r,x-a+r[ \subset B^c$ . Now consider the interval $]x-r,x+r[$. Let $c \in ]x-r,x+r[$ . Then, $x-r < c < x+r$ and thus also $x-a-r < c-a <x-a+r$. Because $]x-a-r,x-a+r[ \subset B^c$ , $c-a \in B^c$. This is equivalent to $c-a \notin B$. Because this is valid for all $a \in A$, I can conclude that $c \in C^c$ and thus $]x-r,x+r[ \subset C^c$. So there exists an $r>0$ such that $]x-r,x+r[ \subset C^c$ for all $x \in C^c$. This means that all points of $C^c$ are interior points and thus is $C$ closed.

Is this a correct proof ? I could not find any errors in my reasoning but I noticed that I haven't used the fact that $A$ is closed, which makes me think that this proof is not correct. Also, I haven't used the fact that $A$ and $B$ are bounded. I also wish an explanation without the use of the term compactness, but a proof by using the definition of a closed set.

Comment: You're definitely going to have to use that $A$ is closed, because $(0,1) + [1,2] = (1,3)$ which is not closed. You may be able to find a mistake by tracing through the proof using that example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the sum of two compact sets in $\mathbb R^n$ is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432845/prove-that-the-sum-of-two-compact-sets-in-mathbb-rn-is-compact)

Comment: @Brozovic, no because I would rather have an explanation without the term compactness. A proof by using the definition of a closed set maybe.

Comment: Why does $c-a\not\in B$ for all $a$ imply that $c\in C^c?$ I think your overall approach is probably ok, but I think you'll find that fleshing this out shows you the hole in your proof, which I think you can patch up.

Comment: @AdrianKeister , because if $c-a \notin B$ for all $a \in A$ then $c$ can not be written als a sum of two terms for which one term is in $A$ and the other term is in $B$. I cannot see why this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Let $A$ and $B$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ and define $C=A+B$. Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence in $C$, then there exist sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ in $A$ and $B$, respectively, such that $c_n = a_n + b_n$. Now, since $A$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ with limit in $A$, and similarly there exists a convergent subsequence $\{b_{n_{k_l}}\}$ with limit in $B$. It follows that $\{c_{n_{k_l}}\}$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{c_n\}$, and since compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in metric spaces, $C$ is compact (and therefore closed).

Comment: Why does $c_n = a_n + b_n$ with $\{c_n \}$ being convergent imply that $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$ is convergent ? As a counter example, consider the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ with $x_n = n-n$. This sequence converges to $0$ but its individual terms diverge. I suspect it's because $\{ a_n \}$  and $\{ b_n \}$ are bounded, but where and how do I use that argument ?

Comment: @Einsteinwasmyfather $A$ and $B$ are bounded, so necessarily any sequence of elements from one of those sets is bounded.

Comment: What about the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ with $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $\{ b_n \}$ with $b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: @Einsteinwasmyfather I have revised my answer.