# Let $E$ be a t.v.s. and $A, B \subseteq E$ with $A$ compact and $B$ closed. Then $A+B$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove below theorem. My proof is much simpler than [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515496/sum-of-closed-and-compact-set-in-a-tvs) one. I'm afraid that I made some subtle mistake. Could you have a check on it?

> Let $E$ be a topological vector space, and $A, B \subseteq E$ with $A$ compact and $B$ closed. Then $C :=A+B$ is closed.

**My attempt:** Let $(c_d)_{d\in D}$ be a net in $C$ that converges to $c\in E$. By axiom of choice, we can write $c_d = a_d+b_d$ for some $a_d \in A$ and $b_d \in B$. Because $A$ is compact, the net $(a_d)_{d\in D}$ has a convergent subnet $(a_{\psi (d)})_{d \in D}$ such that $a_{\psi (d)} \to a$ for some $a \in A$. By definition of net convergence, $c_{\psi (d)} \to c$. Then $b_{\psi (d)} = c_{\psi (d)} - a_{\psi (d)} \to c-a$. Because $B$ is closed, $c-a \in B$ and thus $c = a + (c-a) \in A + B= C$. This completes the proof.

Comment: To me it is totally fine, but I do not see how this is different than Duchamp Gérard H. E.’s answer in the link you mentioned.

Comment: @SonGohan Ahh I did not scroll down to the other answers.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer to your question, so we can close it if you agree :)

Comment: @SonGohan I will be happy if you do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it is totally fine and it is a nice generalization to spaces that are not sequential spaces (for which the topology is not fully described by sequences). The proof is essentially the same (with some remarks like the use of the axiom of choice). As another reference I post here Duchamp Gérard H. E.’s answer that is very similar to your (correct) work: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079363/865323