# Question about closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Euclidean n-space).
Define $A + B = \{ x + y : x \in A , y \in B \}.$
Now If $A$ and $B$ are closed sets, is $A+B$ also a closed set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $n = 2$, take $A$ to be the $y$-axis and take $B$ to be the positive quadrant of the hyperbola $y = \frac{1}x$. Then $A$ and $B$ are both closed, but $A + B$ is the set of $(x, y)$ such that $x > 0$, which is not closed.

If $A$ and $B$ are both closed and one of them is compact, then $A + B$ is closed.  See [Closed sum of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80974/closed-sum-of-sets) for a proof.

Comment: In your edit, you have written that "A or B are both closed..." I did not get that. should it be "A and B..." ?

Comment: Yes - thanks for pointing out the typo. Now fixed.

Comment: Great. now it's fine.

Answer (score 8):

Not always. Consider in $\mathbb{R}$: $$A = \mathbb{Z}, \quad B = \left\{ n + \frac{1}{n} : n \geqslant 2 \right\}$$ so $\frac{1}{n} \in A + B$ but $0 \not \in A+B$.

Comment: You beat me to it $\ddot{\frown}$!

Comment: awesome ! thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
A + B &= \{ a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\} \\
&= \bigcup_{b \in B} \{ a + b \mid a \in A\} \\
&= \bigcup_{b \in B} (A+b)\,.
\end{align}
If one of the sets $A,B$ is finite, then $A+B$ is closed, because $A+b$ is closed (I think this holds in all normed spaces). But since infinite unions of closed sets are not closed in general, it seems that there should be plenty of counterexamples (two already posted here).

Comment: thanks for giving your point of view.

Comment: If one of the sets is finite, it is bounded, and closed bounded sets in $\mathbb R^n$ are compact. So the rule "finite + closed = closed" is a special case of the rule "compact + closed = closed" mentioned by Rob Arthan.

Comment: Oh thanks I will see that in detail in the link given by him. :)