# Find the set $B$ such that its derived set $B´=A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

help with this excercise,

Find the set $B$ such that its derived set $B´=A$ where,

$$A=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}$$

How??

I try but none... :(

Comment: How would you solve this if $A=\{1\}.$?

Comment: You have not told us what space you are working in. If you are working in $\mathbb R$ then there is no solution, because the derived set must be closed, and $A$ is not closed in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Sometimes when you try to find a set, but fail you eventually have to consider the possibility that such a set does not exist. Then of course when you try to disprove something you may fail, but then you may have more insight in the problem at least...

Answer (score 1):

Such a set *does not exist* for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, because a derived set containing each $\frac{1}{n}$ must also contain 0:

1. Suppose every $1/n$ $(n\in \mathbb{N})$ is a limit point of $B$.
2. Then $B$ contains arbitrarily close approximations to each $1/n$.
3. Then 0 must also be a limit point of $B$.
4. Indeed, if $1/n$ gets arbitrarily close to 0, and members of $B$ get arbitrarily close to each $1/n$, then members of $B$ get arbitrarily close to 0.

   (To see this formally, pick $\epsilon > 0$. The ball around 0 of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ contains some $1/n$. The ball around $1/n$ of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ contains some $y\in B$. The distance between $y$ and 0 is at most $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, by the triangle inequality. Hence for each ε, we can find $y\in B$ within $\epsilon$ of 0, so 0 is a limit point of $B$.)
5. Hence if the set of limit points of $B$ contains $\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, it must also contain 0.
6. There is no set $A$ whose set of limit points includes $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and nothing else.

---

If our goal is to include $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and very little else, we can define $H = \{ \frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, so that $H\cup \{0\}$ has zero as its sole limit point. Then define your set to be:

$$B = \{ x + y \mid x, y \in H\} \cup H.$$

Then if we fix $x$ and vary $y\in H$ in the definition of $B$, we can see that each $x\in H$ is a limit point of $B$, and so is 0. It should be straightforward to see whether any other point $x\notin H$ is a limit point.

(Following answer to distantly-related question: [Example of a countable compact set in the real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912628/example-of-a-countable-compact-set-in-the-real-numbers/1912638#1912638))

Comment: That set has a limit point of 0 which is not in the stipulated A.  Without adding 0 to A, is the problem possible?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, I believe removing 0 from the definition of H, and adding H back into B, solves the problem. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: 0 is still a limit pt of B as the sequence 1/n is in B.  Add 0 to A and the problem will be solvable.

Comment: @WilliamElliot The answer says that no such set exists and that it is due to the fact that $0\in B'$ and $0\notin A$.

Comment: and $A_k= \{\frac{1}{k-1/m}\}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You have not provided enough information to give a unique answer, but one answer could come from studying the integral $\int_0^1{x^m}dx=\left[\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} \right]_0^1=\frac{1}{m+1}$ where $m$ is a nonnegative integer, with x being a real number between $0$ and $1$.

If you integrate the function again (being a repeated or successive integral depending on which book on calculus you read), what is the result?

$$\frac{1}{m+1}\int_0^1{x^{m+1}}dx=\frac{1}{m+1}\left[\frac{x^{???}}{???} \right]_0^1=\frac{1}{(m+1)(???)}$$

Therefore if the sets B and A are related by the rules of calculus, then you get an answer. Of course any number of other plausible associations and answers may exist.

Comment: It's not clear how this hint would be useful. It rather looks like you didn't understand the question, for example what the definition of derived set is. According to the answer of user326210 there is **no** solution to this problem.

Comment: @skyking: I will leave my "incorrect" answer because the general-topology tag was added by B. Goddard (not the OP or Original Poster) **after** I first added my HINT,  to say without defining terms you could make a range of plausible associations to get an answer. In any case it would be much clearer if the "derived" set as I now understand it was called the "limit point set" or even the "limit set".

Comment: Try google for "derived set" and you'll see that it's pretty standard notation. For example both wikipedia and wolfam (and other sources) agrees with agrees with the definition. You're not supposed to be required to define terms that are widely accepted.

Comment: @skyking: That's a shame because there is at least one other term in a different field I want to redefine.

Comment: Which term in which field do you want to redefine?

Comment: @skyking: I deleted my comment; I will raise a new question instead.